# Populate blank cells in a column until all populated from repeating list

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use VBA code to populate a list of filtered blank cells.  I decided to make a picture with small example to explain it easier. Column D should be populated with names from col A repeating until each ID has a name.

I have absolutely no idea how to loop it to make it work - it's mind boggling!  I have been searching the web for hours so I am now asking for help. Please note that column C and D are filtered with criteria blanks for column D.

[image: example]

Here is working code to populate blank cells of a filtered list with the same 3 names alternating.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim last As Long
Dim counter As Integer
Dim nameRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

last = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set nameRange = Range("D2:D" & last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

counter = 1

For Each cell In nameRange
    If counter = 1 Then
        cell.Value = "Carrie"
        counter = counter + 1
    ElseIf counter = 2 Then
        cell.Value = "Lisa"
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        cell.Value = "Bob"
        counter = 1
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

thanks for everyone's input - Hopefully, this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If not, the _Super User_ site would be more appropriate. If it is a VBA question, then in general readers will ask to see what you've tried. You mention a loop, so that would be a good start! Could you try a `While()` loop that examines items in the `C` column until it encounters an empty cell?

Comment: @halfer i need vba code to insert with the rest of my code that got me to this point of filtering the ID's that still need a name assigned.  i think if you are going to comment you can at least offer a suggestion.  a while loop is meaningless if you don't know what code block to use in the loop. i can say for each cell in range, or while cell is <> "" fine, but i am here on the site to find out how to populate the blank cell in order from the list of names until it is complete which i can't figure out a way to do it.  so no i don't have code for this specific piece.

Comment: _I think if you are going to comment you can at least offer a suggestion_ - I'm afraid it doesn't work like that here. Though, to be fair, I did offer a suggestion!

Comment: What @halfer is saying is without your current code how are we supposed to do anything but guess.  None of the answers below will work with filtered data.

Comment: Yes, the screenshot doesn't show filtering.

Comment: You should show what code you have **AND** a screenshot that is more like the dataset you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it without the need of filtering the data.

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrowa As Long
Dim lastrowd As Long
Dim counta As Long
Dim rng As Range

counta = 2 'First row of name list in column A

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lastrowa = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowd = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(lastrowd, 5))
        If rng.Value = "" Then
            rng.Value = .Cells(counta, 1).Value
            If counta = lastrowa Then
                counta = 2
            Else
                counta = counta + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Range("D2:D4").Value = Range("A2:A4").Value
Range("D2:D4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D11")
```

If you don't know where column C ends that is easy enough to work out. Something like

```
Range("D2:D4").Value = Range("A2:A4").Value
Range("D2:D4").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("D2"), _
    Range("C2").End(xlDown).Cells(1, 2))
```

If you don't know how far the data extends in column A:

```
Dim last As Integer

last = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("D2:D" & last).Value = Range("A2:A" & last).Value
Range("D2:D" & last).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("D2"), _
    Range("C2").End(xlDown).Cells(1, 2))
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but when i tried it is not working due to the list is filtered.  i am trying to use your answer with special cells visible, but it still isn't working correctly.  i updated my question to specify filtered.

Answer (score 0):

My example doesn't work perfectly, or even well... Its late :)

Create a named range that encapsulates all your "names" (called `namesRange` in my example).
In your "assigned" column put the following formula:

`=INDEX(namesList,ROW()-((INT(ROW()/ROWS(namesList))*ROWS(namesList))),1)`

Update...

Thought about it, and remembered how to excel a little more.. The following is what I was trying to do in my first example.

`=INDEX(namesList,MOD(ROW()-1,ROWS(namesList)-1)+1,1)`

Comment: `ROW()` is very arbitrary, so the list will start with a different name depending on in which row the formula is placed.  To always start at the top make it `ROW(1:1)` which will increment up +1 as it is dragged down.

Comment: @ScottCraner it does start at the top regardless of where its placed? it calculates the name required, given that the OP wanted it to loop through the list

Comment: when placed in row 2 `ROW()-1` will = 1 when placed in row 3 it will equal 2,  It will iterate through the list fine, but will start in a different spot depending on which row the formula starts.  But this is all academic as the OP wanted something that would work with sorted data and this will not achieve the proper iteration with that, which is not your fault but that of the OP not stating what they truly desired in the beginning.